Can `background` be used in table layout in column with Safari
I am unable to use background (as img) in table layout on safari in columns?
Is it known issue?
I tried to search on bugs.webkit.org to see if the bug is reported but couldn't find it.
I tried rows and it worked but not others, it works in Chrome and Firefox without issue.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Can you please provide some more detail on what you are trying to do and update your question to include some of the specific code that you are having trouble with.
